# Digital assets and able to transfer those

Tags: assets, hyperledger-composer, digital-assets

I need some guidance on how to support having access to digital assets and being able to transfer those between other user on the hyperledger via composer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you launch the online Playground:
https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net

From there you can import a range of sample (using the Import/Replace button) that illustrate how to code asset transfer. E.g. Marbles, Car Auction or Animal Tracking.

Comment: Thanks - but I still can't see how I can use composer to implement the encryption of the digital asset - can I access the users private keys/data? so I can generate an new key for the digital asset

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the tag information (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hyperledger-composer/info)

> Hyperledger Composer provides a layer of abstraction on top of the Hyperledger Fabric blockchain. Developers can design in terms of business networks, participants, identity, assets, registries, transactions, events and links, in contrast to the low level abstractions of chaincode and key-value stores.

So if you wish to do something with a digital asset, say an MP3, you need to create a model - similar to an entity-relationship model or an ObjectOriented hierachy. With that you can then define the operations on it.

An actual asset maybe the MP3 wouldn't necessarily be stored - but would be linked to. Composer then handles how this is put onto the underlying fabric - to give your applications the quality of service of Fabric's blockchain but without the requirement to write chain-code etc.

Hope that puts Composer into context, if you need more please include a broader description of your use case/problem you're solving.